# I cant seem to get the input value from UITextField using UIAlertViewController in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift2, uialertview

Using iOS9 and Swift to test this UIAlertViewController. So far I am able to get the popup for the user to enter the text("Email address"). In fact I have the entered text by the user as well. but the the text displays: Optional("test@test.com"). I apologies in advance but I am rookie at the moment. Thank you so much in advance for the hints.

```
@IBAction func UserForgotPasswordAction(sender: AnyObject) {

 func handleCancel(alertView: UIAlertAction!)
    {
        print("Cancelled !!")
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter your Email Address", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
     UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField) in
        print("generating the TextField")
        textField.placeholder = "Email address"
        textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        print("THE Input 01: \(textField.text)")
    })
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:handleCancel))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

        if let textField2 = alert.textFields!.first {
            print("THE Input: \(textField2.text)")
            PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground("\(textField2.text)")
        }

    }))


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code inside action by adding `!` as its optional:

```
if let textField2 = alert.textFields!.first {
        print("THE Input: \(textField2.text!)")
        PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground("\(textField2.text!)")
    }
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much!!